# Syntax error javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm getting the following error:

> uncaught syntax error, unrecognized expression : #

It appears to be coming from this line of code:

```
bb.error=function(br){throw"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+br
};
```

Do you know where my error is from? Is it related to the semicolon? It seems odd that it's failing, because I'm doing something very similar in other parts of my code and it works fine.

Comment: It's impossible to reproduce your problem purely from your code given. Could you provide some more context?

Comment: The provided code seems fine (I'd suggest to add the missing `;`, anyhow). You should at the code, where this function is called. You'll probably find your mistake there.

Comment: In which environment are you getting that error? browser? node? rhino?

Comment: Please post _your_ code, not jquery's.

Comment: Turns out string starting with a newline (or anything other than "<") is not considered HTML string in certain libraries. Is that the case for you?

Comment: OP is not interested to get the solution... and we all are dying to answer :p

Comment: What are you trying to pass your function (as br) ? string? object? may console.log(br) help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out string starting with a newline (or anything other than "<") is not considered HTML string in jQuery 1.9.

This is just a guess because you are not providing enough details to know for sure what your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

This is because u itself throwing error otherwise code is perfect.

if you update "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " to "testing message" it will start showing updated message.

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/Y8r8K/2/)

```
var bberror = function (br) {
    throw "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + br
};

bberror("my custom error");
```

Comment: If I've read the question correctly, that's not related to the question at all -- that's just the code which throws an error. That's not the code that's actually failing though, which is what this question is about.

Comment: i will keep this answer until OP response.